# Javascript - How to get filter() to return match result

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to return the result of `match` to `filter`. I tried `forEach` but it causes my script to crash without an error for some reason I can't seem to resolve. If within the `filter` I log `element.match(/regex/)[1]` it logs the output I want. When I return that however, it returns the whole string (Not just the match). Here's the code:

```
let myAr = ['{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"100000077777226","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AauUajLpeWuhLBG3jk4ypnhABBcEcbN4M8Z2F6J_CQaQXEhPwL-3j1_dX5vhAleK3K7rjlzqJwnG4xGGaGdFk7Eb","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"1509941759"}',
        '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"711427743","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AasHfdsp_Gkdbs3_B4K-_5cN8Y0ZqJPVdm4MYXBzUoXs5QyNoPir8LEYK_RsMpQMxwI","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"1509941759"}',
        '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"500890765","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AasBuRKr2vnMecj6ozdELAcZnUPL1FD3ojLSVrYrTckKy_pB2HekM693oJwKD0yH41Y","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"1509941759"}',
        ];

let resultAr = myAr.filter(function(element) {
        if (element != '#' && element != null) {
            console.log( element.match(/eng_tid":"(\d*)",/)[1]); // this logs what I want
            return element.match(/eng_tid":"(\d*)",/)[1]; // this doesn't return what I want
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
console.log(resultAr);
```

How do I return what's output in the first console logger?

Comment: Are you thinking of `map`? `filter` doesn’t return an array of _modified_ elements, it just _filters_ them, as the name implies. Also, is there any reason, you don’t just parse the JSON and instead rely on regexes?

Comment: There's that too. The JSON is coming from a data attribute of an HTML a tag so my brain just wasn't much in JSON mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'map', instead of 'filter'.

```
let myAr = ['{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"100000077777226","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AauUajLpeWuhLBG3jk4ypnhABBcEcbN4M8Z2F6J_CQaQXEhPwL-3j1_dX5vhAleK3K7rjlzqJwnG4xGGaGdFk7Eb","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"1509941759"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"711427743","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AasHfdsp_Gkdbs3_B4K-_5cN8Y0ZqJPVdm4MYXBzUoXs5QyNoPir8LEYK_RsMpQMxwI","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"1509941759"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"500890765","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AasBuRKr2vnMecj6ozdELAcZnUPL1FD3ojLSVrYrTckKy_pB2HekM693oJwKD0yH41Y","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"1509941759"}',
    ];

let resultAr = myAr.map(function(element) {
    if (element != '#' && element != null) {
        return element.match(/eng_tid":"(\d*)",/)[1];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
console.log(resultAr);
```

Comment: That's got her. Thanks